# Extracting Salesforce Data Using the Data Loader Command Line

Tags: data-loader

i want to create encryption key and encrypted password to import data into salesforce using data loader CLI, But it is giving me error, you can see in the image that i've uploaded. Please help me with this.
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE)! Please do not post error text (or code) exclusively as screenshots - it is not as accessible to users who use screen readers or other assistive technology. Instead, copy your error text and paste it in the SFSE editor with a greater than symbol (>) at the beginning to format it as a quote block.

Answer (score 1):

Before using Data Loader CLI install JRE and setup JAVA HOME in your system from [Zulu](https://www.azul.com/downloads/?os=windows&package=jre) and try doing it again.

[image]

[image]

Hope this helps.

Regards

Prince Sharma